# Authenticate user through google login in android app

Tags: android, authorization, google-api

I want authenticate user in my android app through google login and then dispaly his name and email if he login(authenticate) successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at this: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/